# dreamhost with thumbs_up update RubyGems version dependency issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, passenger, dreamhost

I'm trying to set up my ror site on dreamhost, however, I'm using a gem (thumbs_up) that requires ruby gems version 1.7.0 and above.

Current version is:

```
terebellum]$ gem -v
1.3.7
```

I tried running " gem update --system" and I got this error:

```
gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

Please advise. See logs below.

Thanks

Limo

```
Installing thumbs_up (0.5.3) /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:170:in `install': thumbs_up requires RubyGems version >= 1.7.0. Try 'gem update --system' to update RubyGems itself. (Gem::InstallError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/source.rb:95:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:271:in `update'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb: 118:in `invoke_task'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/bin/bundle:13
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/bundle:19
[terebellum]$ gem update --system
ERROR: While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in subtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, using Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this is completely unsupported by Debian.
[terebellum]$ gem -v
1.3.7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to [install RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) (since [Dreamhost wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RVM) says it can be done) and Ruby version you need (say `rvm install 1.8.7`). Then any time you want to update Rubygems, you can run `rvm rubygems 1.7.0` (see [RubyGems CLI API](http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/))